# What is the default typeface of the app bar text in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, fonts, appbar

The typeface of the text for the default app bar isn't any of the typefaces that are available by default -- compared all of them visually to the app bar text and none of them matched. The style I'm comparing to is `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`. Any idea how to get text to look like the default text in the app bar?

Here's what I'm talking about:

[image]
*text on the left is the default app bar text and the text on the right is the default android text (sans-serif), but bold -- of the few typefaces that are available by default, this is the closest I could get to the default app bar text
*sans-serif not bold is too thin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems it is `Roboto Medium 20sp` according [this](https://material.google.com/style/typography.html) info.